# Bugzilla - webservice via JSON-RPC

Tags: jquery, web-services, jsonp, bugzilla

Here's what i have tried soo far..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>bugstats.com</title>
  </head>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-json.googlecode.com/files/jquery.json-    1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function hello(){
var myObject = {"method":"User.login", /* is this the right method to call? */
"params":[  { "login" :"user", /*should i include the login credentials here? */
"password" : "pass123" , 
"remember" : "True"} ]  };
var enc = $.toJSON(myObject);

$.ajax({"contentType":"application/json",
    "data": enc, 
    "crossDomain":"true",
    "dataType": "json", 
    "url": "https://bugzilla.company.com/bugzilla/jsonrpc.cgi", /* is this correct or should it be https://bugzilla.company.com/bugzilla/jsonrpc.cgi?method=User.login? */ 
    "type": "POST",
    success: function(){
            alert("Hallelujah");
                console.log(arguments); 

             },
    error: function () {
    alert("Failed")
    }

   });
}
function parseResponse(obj){
 alert("Success")
 console.log(obj)
}
</script>
  <body>
    <h1>bugzilla.com</h1>
    <input type="button" onclick="hello()" value="Click">
</body>
```

Reading upon this [**JSONPRC**](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.html), not getting far.

When i click the button - make a call, to login/do anything for that matter - i get the following error -

```
OPTIONS https://bugzilla.company.com/bugzilla/jsonrpc.cgi 403 (Forbidden) jquery.min.js:19
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://bugzilla.company.com/bugzilla/jsonrpc.cgi. Origin http://172.16.229.137 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

From my understanding, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is caused because of "same origin policy" problem and hence i should use "jsonp". But,Jsonp - i.e, script injection can only be done via GET request. But,if i try the same JS script with a GET request - i get the following :

```
code: 32610
message: "For security reasons, you must use HTTP POST to call the 'User.login' method."
```

Confused on how to connect/login via Web services, i'm clearly doing something silly something majorly wrong here.. would be a great deal of help if anyone can help me connect and fetch the bug details.I've been at it since 8-10 days now.. :(

FYI:

- I do not have access to the server
- I'm on a client setup and accessing the Bugzilla server

Other links,

[**Ajax Call**](http://guy-pyrzak.blogspot.in/2009/07/bugzilla-json-rpc-webservice-with.html)

[**Loggin In**](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html#LOGGING_IN)

[**BugzillaApc**](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User%3aHarthur/BugzillaRPC)

[**Google Groups - Live conversation**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mozilla.support.bugzilla/-kNtcaggyJY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be using the `Bugzilla_login` and `Bugzilla_password` parameters to authenticate every call, which will be GET using jsonp.  Your call will look like the following, using `User.get` as an example:

```
// Method parameters
var params = [{
  /* The authentication parameters */
  "Bugzilla_login": "YourUserName",
  "Bugzilla_password": "YourPassword",
  /* The actual method parameters */
  "ids": [1, 2]
}];
var myObject = {
  "method": "User.get",
  "params": JSON.stringify(params)
};

$.ajax({"contentType": "application/json",
    "data": myObject, /* jQuery will handle URI encoding */
    "crossDomain": "true",
    "dataType": "jsonp", /* jQuery will handle adding the 'callback' parameter */
    "url": "https://bugzilla.company.com/bugzilla/jsonrpc.cgi", 
    "type": "GET",
    ...
```

You have to do it this way because:

- You will be making a cross-domain call
- Because you can't set things like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` you'll have to do it via jsonp (or proxying, but jsonp is simpler)
- jsonp is necessarily a `GET` request, not `POST`

The relevant docs:

- [Connecting via GET](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.html#Connecting_via_GET) - You'll be limited to retrieving information, changes require `POST` calls.
- [Logging in via `Bugzilla_login` and `Bugzilla_password`](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html#LOGGING_IN)

Comment: If i try the above code snippet,i.e. Raw `myObject` for jQuery to process - i get the error => `code: 32000
message: "Could not parse the 'params' argument as valid JSON. Error: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 1 (before "object Object]") at Bugzilla/WebService/Server/JSONRPC.pm line 169. Value: [object Object]"` , But the json string i've given is as per the prescribed method. If i include the `toJson` method before sending - i get `please include a method before sending a request` error comes up..

Comment: @VivekChandra Oops, coded that up a bit too fast, please see the update which should have all the right encodings in the right places.

Comment: It worked.. :) .. thanks a million, but have a small question - in the [__Doc__](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService.html#CALLING_METHODS)'s it says even an array is accepted!, so why is string being accepted and not when params was an array??..

Comment: @VivekChandra Arrays are accepted, but must be URI encoded.  See the "`ids`" parameter in the call above for an example.

Comment: so, `json.stringify` makes it into a string - which is URI encoded?.. and,hence it works ?.. i'm not aware of URI encoding,gotta look into it.. if thats where i was going wrong!,damn.. i should've read the doc's more thoroughly.. :(

Comment: @VivekChandra `JSON.stringify` turns it into a JSON string, jQuery automatically does the URI encoding to the `data` object.